# Why is convolution or FFT breaking in this case?

Tags: fft, convolution, python

It is well-known that convolution in real space corresponds to multiplication in the reciprocal space. Yet, I obtain different results using both methods in the case that I'm going to present. I am sure that I made a mistake, but I really can't see where.

The Python code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Create a signal: a gaussian
sig = np.exp(-(np.linspace(-10, 10, 1024))**2)
# Calculate its FFT transform
F_SIG = np.fft.fft(sig)

# Create an FIR filter from its transform
F_KER = np.empty_like(sig, dtype=np.complex128)
F_KER[:len(F_KER)//2] = np.exp(-1j*np.pi/3)
F_KER[len(F_KER)//2:] = np.exp(1j*np.pi/3)
F_KER[[0, len(F_KER)//2]] = np.cos(np.pi/3)
# Get its inverse FFT transform
kern = np.fft.ifft(F_KER) # is actually pure real value
print("Max real value:\t", np.abs(kern.real).max())
print("Max imaginary value:\t", np.abs(kern.imag).max())
print("Therefore 'kern' can be considered pure real.")
kern = kern.real

# From math books, 
# multiplication in Fourier/Frequency space <-> convolution in real space
multFFT_sig = np.fft.ifft(F_SIG*F_KER).real # Again, pure real, can be checked
conv_sig = np.convolve(sig, kern, "full")


# Plot both of them
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0,1024])
plt.title("Convolution vs. FFT multiply")
plt.plot(multFFT_sig)
plt.plot(conv_sig)


# Padding problem? Circular convolution problem?
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0,1024])
plt.title("Original signals")
plt.plot(sig)
plt.plot(kern)
plt.legend(["Orig. signal", "Conv. kernel"])

plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0,2048])
plt.title("Zero-padded signals")
p_sig = np.append([0]*512, np.append(sig, [0]*512))
p_kern = np.append(kern[:512], np.append([0]*1024, kern[512:]))
plt.plot(p_sig)
plt.plot(p_kern)
plt.legend(["pad. signal", "pad. conv. kernel"])

# Calculate convolution padded terms
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0,2048])
plt.title("Padded convolution vs. FFT multiply")
p_F_SIG = np.fft.fft(p_sig)
p_F_KER = np.fft.fft(p_kern)
p_multFFT_sig = np.fft.ifft(p_F_SIG*p_F_KER).real # Again, pure real, can be checked
p_conv_sig = np.convolve(p_sig, p_kern, "full")
plt.plot(p_multFFT_sig)
plt.plot(p_conv_sig)
```

The output:

```
Max real value:  0.551327165647
Max imaginary value:     2.55232033425e-15
Therefore 'kern' can be considered pure real.
```

[image]

I also tested with `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` and compared with the analytical answer: the FFT multiplication gives the right answer (clearly asymmetrical peak in blue) while the convolution (in real space or using FFT) is wrong.

**Why is convolution not working as intended?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, zero-padding is the issue, however not as you would except...

@Soren is only partially right: you can add zeros at the beginning, middle or end of the signal just as you did, but absolutely not as you wish.

What's the general rule?

> Look at how the signal repeats with and without zeros and choose the
>   place that distorts the signal the least.

What does it mean?

- In the case of a real, discrete and **aperiodic** time-space signal, there is a causal relationship between the value at n and the value at n+1. So all these values should be considered as a bloc, adding zeros in the middle would distort it. Here is an obvious reason from your code, you had a proper Gaussian, not something like this:

[image]

- In the case of your convolution kernel, it's a bit more complicated. What do the last taps (second half) mean?

  - In the aperiodic DTFT (i.e. linear convolution, as opposed to circular), these mean that the convolved values depends of both `[n, n+1, n+2, ...]` (as expected) but also `[len - 1, len - 2, len - 3, ...]` (where `len` corresponds to the end of the array without padding). This "classical" linear convolution can be simulated by padding the end/beginning of the signal.
  - In the periodic DFT (circular convolution), the taps of the second half actually correspond to the values `[n-1, n-2, n-3, ...]` (**not** the values by the end of the signal).

`np.convolve` and bunch try to do a "classical" linear convolution while you seem to want a non-classical one (zeros added in the middle). Here is a comparison: 
[image]

As I understood, the actual kernel you want is the one described in "your kernel".

You can easily get the right kernel by fftshifting:

```
kern = np.fft.fftshift(kern)
```

This has the effect of centering your DC (using linear phase shifting) and then you can just pad zeros at the beginning/end as much as you wish and use the standard convolution/filtering tools.

---

In the end, this was an interesting question: people usually just pad blindly using convolution functions or options from the FFT transform without ever wondering what they are doing. Some even put `fftshift`s out of habit every time they deal with anything resembling a kernel.

Answer (score 0):

When zero-padding you should insert zeros after the signal that you wish to pad.

Change

```
p_sig = np.append([0]*512, np.append(sig, [0]*512))
p_kern = np.append(kern[:512], np.append([0]*1024, kern[512:]))
```

to

```
p_sig = np.append(sig,np.zeros(1024))
p_kern = np.append(kern,np.zeros(1024))
```

and you'll get a correct result.